# Jquery check an array values ranging from 63 to 87

Tags: jquery

I am sure there is a smarter way to specify a range of values to check from

```
if ( $.inArray(this.selectedIndex, [63, 64, 65, ......, 86, 87]) > -1 ){ 
     $('.div').fadeIn();
}
```

How can I say from 63 to 87 inside the [] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can specify the array with a function

```
var initArray = function(begin,end){
    var arrays = [];
        for(var i=parseInt(begin);i<=parseInt(end);i++){
            arrays.push(i);
        }
        return arrays;
    }
```

and use it in your code like this

```
if ( $.inArray(this.selectedIndex, initArray(63,87)) > -1 ){ 
    $('.div').fadeIn();
}
```